# 'nx generate lib direcotyName/libname" adding directory name to the library name

Tags: angular, nrwl-nx

I am trying to generate a library under a directory via above command in angular nx workspace.
It is generating correctly but in angular.json (and few other filex) when it's adding the entry for the new library it changed the library name to a new one by prepeding directories with '-'.

I want to get rid of this behavior as I am ensuring that the library name won't be duplicate. Is there any option (option combination) through which I can achieve this.

Answer (score 5):

Can you try using the correct flag that exists to specify the directory? This is the command that should work for you:

```sh
nx generate @nrwl/angular:library --name=my-lib-name --directory=custom-dir
```

Let me know if this works! :)

Comment: Doesn't work. This command will generate lib with the name `custom-dir-my-lib-name`. 

There is an issue on GitHub https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/3869